# How to combine Titanium with TiBeacon?

Tags: titanium, ibeacon

Im trying to do a project with Estimote beacons. For the convenience of myself I'd like to make an application with Titanium.

For connecting with the iBeacons I found the TiBeacon module (https://github.com/jbeuckm/TiBeacons).

I honestly don't know how to go further with this. I can implement the module in my project, but how can I get actual results on my screen?

Comment: You can check there example at [github link](https://github.com/jbeuckm/TiBeacons/blob/master/example/app.js).

Comment: When I upload this to my phone, I only get the 'Titanium Alloy' screen..

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to first learn Titanium development.  This example code, turtle indicated, specifically shows an TiBeacon use without any additional UI.  You can use Ti.API.log to have output go t the Titanium debugger in a connected device debugging example. To learn more about Titanium UI: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI